# Number of rows returned for each point PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I have two datasets of points. I want to calculate the number of points in table B within 2km of each location in table A and store this as an integer column.

I use the code below to return each point from A within 2km of B, but I am unsure how to extract the number of occurrences of A in this result and store it to a new column.

```
select a.name, b.incident_zip 
from ny_air_bnb as a, nypubs as b 
where(st_transform(a.geom,2263) <-> st_transform(b.geom,2263) <= 2000)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do you mean by "number of occurrences of a"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want window functions:

```
select a.name, b.incident_zip, count(*) over (partition by a.name)
from ny_air_bnb a join
     nypubs as b 
     on (st_transform(a.geom,2263) <-> st_transform(b.geom,2263) <= 2000);
```

EDIT:

If you want to store this in `ny_air_bnb`, you need `update`:

```
update ny_air_bnb a
    set col = (select count(*)
               from nypubs p
               where st_transform(a.geom, 2263) <-> st_transform(p.geom, 2263) <= 2000
              );
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is almost exactly what I am after! I just need to add that resulting count variable to a column of its own. Thank you again!

Comment: @BenGuilfoyle . . . I don't understand your comment.  The count *is* in a separate column.

Comment: I would like to have that "count" column appended to the ny_air_bnb column

Comment: Count is clearly a numeric value. Please explain what you mean by "append" it to  column.